# Unable to access the public IP address of an EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2

I have a Spring Boot application running on port `8080` on a Ubuntu 20.04 AWS EC2 instance. The instance has the following inbound rule:

```
Port range | Protocol |  Source
   8080    |   TCP    | 0.0.0.0/0
```

It seems to be networking issue, since I am able to run the following command on the instance:

```
curl ec2-<public-ip>.<zone>.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/health
```

whereas the same command doesn't work from my local machine. `ping` doesn't work either.

The routing table has an entry pointing to the Internet Gateway of the VPC:

```
Destination    |      Target      |     Status      |   Propagated
0.0.0.0/0      |     igw-<igwId>  |      active     |      No
```

The Network ACLs has the default settings:

```
Rule number   |    Type    | Protocol  | Port range | Source    | Allow/Deny
100           | All traffic|    All    |    All     | 0.0.0.0/0 |    Allow
*             | All traffic|    All    |    All     | 0.0.0.0/0 |    Deny
```

An important note is that I am able to ssh to the instance using its public IP address. I ran out of things to try, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe your spring boot app is not bind to 0.0.0.0?

Comment: Try `curl <public-ip>:8080/health` from the instance itself. This will force the traffic to go out of the VPC and back in again. Using the `ec2-<public-ip>.<zone>.compute.amazonaws.com` URL from within a VPC will actually resolve to a **private IP address** if the destination is in the same VPC, so it isn't a test of the full network configuration. Let us know the results!

Comment: `curl <public-ip>:8080/health` works as well.

Comment: _Maybe your spring boot app is not bind to 0.0.0.0?_

Would `curl <public-ip>:8080/health` work in that case?

Comment: I realized that the first log line of the service is
`Starting BackgroundCheckEntryPoint on ip-<private-ip> with PID ...`

Comment: So all requests work on the instance itself:
`curl <public-ip>:8080/health`, `curl localhost:8080/health`, `curl 127.0.0.1:8080/health`.